# How to install grunt on staging server.?

Tags: magento2, grunt, staging

I just want to edit some files on staging server.
How can i install grunt on staging server.?

I have run this command:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

error showing that `npm: command not found`

How can i install grunt on staging server.?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your server setup, instructions for different servers can be found on https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager

For the sites I work on this works:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
```

That is not the latest version, for the latest check the link above.

Then navigate to the directory of your `packages.json` and run

```
npm install
```

From there you should be able to follow the instructions [here (dev docs)](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install nodejs, npm, and grunt-cli¶

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs 
$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli `enter code here`
```